# Could the Killing process privilege in SQL Server be assigned to 1 user for 1 database only?

Tags: sql-server, privileges, kill-process

I do not know how to work with the management of privileges in SQL Server. I have a hosting that offers me SQL Server database. If any problem of the type -`an object is blocked`- occurs I need to create a ticket, report that I need to kill the process that is blocking that object and wait that the admin do the operation.

I do not have the privilege to kill process. I do not need to wait too much but in order to respond fast to any problem of this type, I would like to do that myself.

Question:

Is it possible somehow to assign the killing privilege in order that my user could kill only the process attached to the databases where I am owner?.

If this is possible it would be great to know how this works.

Answer (score 1):

The technical answer: yes, it's possible. It'd looks something like this:

- All of this is going to go into a stored procedure. It should probably take one argument: the process to kill.
- Figure out what database the process is running in (look at how sp_who2 does it as IIRC none of the "official" system DMVs expose this before SQL 2012)
- Does that processes database context match one that you own? If yes, allow the kill. If no, don't.

Now that the proc is written, you'll need someone with sysadmin privileges to sign the procedure cryptographically.  This provides the procedure magical powers that allow it to do powerful things (like kill a process).

The real world answer: none of the above matters if your hosting company is not willing to consider it. And they might or they might not.

Comment: In addition to signing, you can also do this with `EXECUTE AS owner` and, as with signing, be careful about who you `GRANT EXECUTE` to. In addition, it is important to note that the session's context database might not be the current database even though that's where the work is being done, and a session's context might indicate the current database even if their work involves other databases.

Comment: I don't understand how the above answer solves the problem to KILL instruction.